# Difference between delphi pe file format and win32 pe file

Tags: delphi, portable-executable

As per my knowledge delphi files having same structure as win32 pe files. And the only difference in resource section i.e RCDATA resource section contains resource with name DVCLAL

My questions are:

1. Is there any difference in headers of win32 pe and delphi pe.
2. If there is no difference is no difference in structure then how to differentiate.
3. If there is difference then what it is?
4. What changes can be done by malware writers in delphi files.Any example.
5. What are the file formats of delphi file and win32 pe file.

Comment: PE format is documented very well. You can even get an A3 wall poster. Why ask?

Comment: I have a feeling *none* of those questions asks what you *really* want to know. What's promting you too ask these questions at all?

Comment: How the malware writers does changes in delphi compiled file .?

Comment: That still is not clear. Try to give some background and examples.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such thing as a Delphi PE file. Delphi compiled executables, on Windows, use the common platform format, which is PE.